# HL7 performance testing with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, hl7

I'm new to JMeter and trying to send HL7 messages to test performance of application. Unfortunately i didn't find much information over the internet.
My first query is — is JMeter support HL7 messages to be send. If yes then do I need any plugin for it?
I am using `TCP sampler` for sending messages, is this a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this JMeter [TCPClient plugin](https://github.com/avisi/jmeter-mllp-tcpclient) for [TCP sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) for sending messages over MLLP to a [HL7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Level_7) interface engine.

1. Clone plugin repo.
2. Build using Maven - `mvn install`
3. Copy compiled plugin jar file to `<jmeter_home>/lib/`
4. Restrat JMeter
5. Create new [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
6. Add a [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) to the Thread Group
7. Specify `nl.avisi.jmeter.mllpsampler.MllpTCPClient` as the `TCP client classname` in the `TCP Sampler`.
8. Enter a `hostname` and `portnumber` in the `TCP Sampler`, add a `HL7` text message, set no delay
9. Fire away!

Also, check this article to get more information about:
[Performance testing of Health Care Applications](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/10/webinar-performance-testing-a-healthcare-application-with-hl7-jmeter/)

Comment: Great! You may accept the answer and upvote it to help other people find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JMeter supports the protocols which are under the hood of its [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), some protocols are available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Looking into [Application Infrastructure](http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=Application_Architecture):

[image]

JMeter supports all the mentioned protocols.

---

With regards to TCP - we don't know, i.e. it might be the case you need to mimic only TCP transport or you might have to consider all the mentioned above. Double check your [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)s and determine which protocol(s) is(are) in scope and once done you should be able to proceed with the coding. Remember one small requirement which applies to all load tests: a test conducted by the load test tool must represent the real-life application usage as close as possible. So if you have only TCP requests in scope - TCP Sampler might be a viable approach, however personally I would go for [HAPI](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/) library using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) sampler - this way you will be able to perform [parameterization/correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) much easier as you will be able to [build messages](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/xref/ca/uhn/hl7v2/examples/CreateAMessage.html) / [parse responses](https://hapifhir.github.io/hapi-hl7v2/xref/ca/uhn/hl7v2/examples/ExampleParseMessages.html) in cleaner way.